# How to inline a GAS library to speed up script?

Tags: google-apps-script, libraries

The documentation for libraries states that they should be avoided in order to speed up the script.
Is there a way to inline a library?
I assume that there should be a way if the sources are available? 
Will just copy&pasting the sources of the library into my main script work?

Answer (score 2):

Copy 'n paste should work, given you don't have any name conflicts. But you'll have to rename all the calls to your library removing the library name.

It's probably possible to create a constructor function to keep the namespace exactly the same. So you could you use the library or paste its code without changing the rest of the script.

Anyway, I think the documentation is a little harsh about this "speed improvement" of not using libraries. It's not that your script will run faster without a library, it'll just take a little less time to load. I think this is only relevant to do if you're writing addons or some massively used script with lots of UI interactions, etc.

Comment: [Bruce Mcpherson addressed this not too long ago on the G+ community](https://plus.google.com/+AndrewRoberts1/posts/Zq2mgNYo94q) and said: "I've done some measurements and haven't been able to find any significant differences measurable outside the normal variability of the apps script environment. (in other words the slight variations in performance of the environment outweigh any observable performance in libraries versus inline)..."

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but it seems relevant still, so I'll post my thoughts on this :) (bear in mind that this is no expert opinion though and more of a thought as to why the docs. are warning us).

Using a library doesn't seem to have a noticeable effect on my scripts. But my thought is that if I don't use them sparingly I will, over time, start to see a degradation in running times.

This would be due to my scripts using libraries, that in turn use some other libraries, that still use other libraries. It will quickly become library hell, if we're not being careful.

So let's adhere to the warnings and use libraries cautiously. Then everyone will be happy and hell will wait another day.

Answer (score 0):

The [OAuth2 for Apps Script library](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) includes a tool to automatically transform its source code (multiple files) into a single file (easy to copy). The result is the file [OAuth2.gs](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/main/dist/OAuth2.gs).

To see the automatic generation tool in action, do the following steps.

1. clone the repository
2. `npm ci`
3. `npm run dist`

It should be doable to modify the `dist` script to generate your own dist files.