# How much slower is a script that uses a library in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, shared-libraries, execution-time

If I have multiple scripts that need to share code, one way to do that is via adding a [Library in Google Apps Scripting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries). However, at the top of the help page, it warns:

> **Warning**: A script that uses a library [doesn't run as quickly](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#avoid_libraries_in_ui-heavy_scripts) as it would if all the code were contained within a single script project. Although libraries can make development and maintenance more convenient, use them sparingly in projects where speed is critical. Because of this issue, library use should be limited in [add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview).

The linked article says:

> ### Avoid libraries in UI-heavy scripts
>
> [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) are a convenient way to reuse code, but they slightly increase the time it takes to start the script. This delay isn't noticeable for relatively long-running scripts...

However, nowhere does it mention how much more execution time it takes to run a script with a library vs. one without a library. In some of their examples, they show a script that takes 20+ seconds to run, in which case a +3 second delay could be "unnoticeable". However, if my script usually takes 2 seconds to run, a 3 second delay becomes a lot more noticeable.

Thus having a rough estimate as to how much time a library adds to execution would be helpful.

What's an estimate as to the amount of time a library adds to the execution time of a Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 2):

From [Measuring library load speed](https://ramblings.mcpher.com/gassnippets2/measuring-library-load-speed/)

> **Findings**
> In summary this means that I find no real penalty for loading libraries. In fact, with parallelism the library versions seem to perform a little better than when all the code is local. I can’t explain it but it seems consistent.

Related

- [How to inline a GAS library to speed up script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34098464/1595451)
- [How to get the best perfomance in Google Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41558890/1595451)
- [Does the ObjApp makes the app script slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43462682/1595451)
- [Anyone actually measure the performance impact of using library imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64662313/1595451) (no answers at this time)

Comment: Please note that these measurements were apparently done under the legacy (Rhino) runtime, not under V8. Which can be seen from the following quote in a different blog post on the same site: ...

Comment: "I haven’t tested this in V8 yet, but in the legacy environment I found no measureable evidence that this was actually true – see Measuring library load speed. A much bigger disincentive for libraries is the difficulty in keeping them up to date and in sync and the potential for compromise from using someone elses code, if you’re planning to use public libraries." - https://ramblings.mcpher.com/5-years-in-apps-script-what-a-change/

Answer (score 0):

I have a web app that I have always deployed under the legacy runtime, that uses 7 libraries. Under the legacy runtime (Rhino) adding libraries does not seem to have much impact and my `doGet` takes only 0.2 s . Under V8 however, `doGet` takes 4.1 s . Under V8, when I remove 4 out of the 7 libraries `doGet` takes 1.4 s . I observe this for other functions of my web app as well, every server side function that is run seems to suffer from the same constant delay for loading the libraries.

Note: The 7 libraries have libraries themselves as well (which probably makes things slower than one might otherwise expect under V8).

Small note: This is not entirely surprising to me as it was already my experience that V8 can be much slower than Rhino (I think JDBC may be slower under V8). Also, libraries cannot be debugged under V8 (so maybe there is simply not as much support for libraries (yet?) under V8).